# Deserialize complex XML to C# object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd, xml-parsing

I have XML in this format -

```
<Areas>
  <Area>
    <Property Name="Test11">a1</Property>
    <Property Name="Test12">a2</Property>
    <Property Name="Test13">a3</Property>
    <Property Name="Test14">a4</Property>
    <Property Name="Test15">a5</Property>
  </Area>
  <Area>
    <Property Name="Test21">b1</Property>
    <Property Name="Test22">b2</Property>
    <Property Name="Test23">b3</Property>
    <Property Name="Test24">b4</Property>
    <Property Name="Test25">b5</Property>
  </Area>
</Areas>
```

I generated the class using xsd.exe provided by Microsoft as -

```
[Serializable()]
    public partial class Areas
    {
        [XmlArrayItem("Property", typeof(AreasAreaProperty))]
        public AreasAreaProperty[][] Area { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public partial class AreasAreaProperty
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlText()]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Code for deserializing is -

```
private void Deserialize()
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Areas));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader xr = new XmlTextReader(fs);
            Areas a = (Areas)xs.Deserialize(xr);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

But at the time of deserilaization, i am getting this error -
**Cannot convert type 'AreasAreaProperty[]' to 'AreasAreaProperty'**
I am getting this error at the time of creation of object of XMLSerializer.

How to solve this issue?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've seen this before. XSD.exe isn't perfect and so you need to tinker with the results a little bit. In the following code, on the last line where you have the [][], remove one of the [] so that it's "public AreasAreaProperty[] Area..."

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class Areas
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Property", typeof(AreasAreaProperty))]
    public AreasAreaProperty[][] Area { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. The error is not coming anymore but when i check the value of object a. It contains only values for the last Area. How to retrieve the values for the area above?

Comment: do you mean something like
foreach( AreasAreaProperty a in foobar.Area )
?

Comment: @RohitVats Did you ever figure out how to get both Area's? I'm trying to do the same thing and haven't got it yet. Please post if you solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar troubles in the past, have a look at the answers to these:

- [Trouble with XML Deserialization into XSD generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419316/trouble-with-xml-deserialization-into-xsd-generated-classes)
- [.NET xsd importer creates unserializable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188930/net-xsd-importer-creates-unserializable-class)

If you have knowledge about your schema you should try and add it to the xsd and not leave everything up to the xsd.exe tool.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the fourth line of your Deserialize() method be

```
    Areas a = (Areas)xs.Deserialize(xr);
```

instead of

```
    Area a = (Area)xs.Deserialize(xr);
```

since your root element is .

Comment: Sory, that's just a typo. I have corrected it in the question. Actually i am getting this error at the very first line of the method..